# How can I convert a (Py)Gtk Gio.ThemedIcon to anything usable in (Py)Qt5 (QImage, QIcon, etc)?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gtk3, pygtk

I have this code that gets a list of all the programs in my linux system capable of opening a png file:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

app_list = Gio.app_info_get_all_for_type('image/png')
```

then I can get the program's icon by:

```py
app = app_list[0]
g_icon = app.get_icon()
```

This returns `<Gio.ThemedIcon object at 0x7f2681640d80 (GThemedIcon at 0x25500a0)>`.
How can I convert this `Gio.ThemedIcon` object to anything (pixbuf, bytes, etc) that I can then use to create a QIcon or a QImage?

Comment: What's the rationale behind mixing gtk and qt in one project?

Comment: I created a GUI program with PyQt5 but then realized some of the things that I need for my program are readily available in Gtk. Some even impractical with PyQt5. One example of impracticality would be I can't properly copy an image to clipboard with `QClipboard` because of some problem Qt has with XFCE4's clipman. Could easily do it with Gtk's clipboard.

Comment: You should prototype and test really well before adopting this technique. I'm not sure whether glib and qt's mainloops are compatible.

Comment: Yeah, I might just change this program to use Gtk for everything. Just not right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ThemedIcon](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gio-2.0/classes/ThemedIcon.html) has the `get_names()` function that returns a list of possible *theme names*. You can use the static [`fromTheme()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme) to get the icon in Qt:

```
app = app_list[0]
g_icon = app.get_icon()
for name in g_icon.get_names():
    icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme(name)
    if not icon.isNull():
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I copy pasted your code and made some required modifications but it didn't work. The `icon` was always `Null`.

Comment: What modifications? I just did a cuple of tests and it works fine, I can do some further checking, but knowing what changes you did might help understand what could be wrong.

Comment: Nothing that should have mattered: https://pastebin.com/eqGQ9WbB. Did you run the checks with "image/png" as well?

Comment: @オパラ I created a basic example to test the combination of Gtk mime types and Qt support, then show the available applications for each mime type and (possibly) their icons. Can you test it? https://gist.github.com/MaurizioB/68d7c961a7d6d795c920f30ddc7d20ca

Comment: Tried running exactly what you posted, nothing happens, all I get is an incomplete depreciation warning in the terminal.
`DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python: winGeo = QtCore.QRect(`

Comment: @オパラ That's just a warning, and you can ignore it. Can you clarify what you mean by "nothing happens"? Please consider that filling the model requires some time (at least a few seconds).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I hadn't considered it'd take some time to load. I checked under "image/png" and found all the applications I was hoping for. Programs' icon is shown twice though: https://imgur.com/wysLN80.png

Comment: That's supposed to happen: if you closely look at my code, I create an *expanded* image whenever more than one icon name is provided. I strongly suggest you to study my code, as it will help you with both understanding how to properly get the icon *and* how models, QIcons, QPixmaps and QPainter work. That said, since my above example works, I believe that my answer was invalid to you due to your modifications.

Comment: It would seem so. Still, I don't understand how any of my modifications could have caused anything since it was just me looping through a list of app icons instead of using one single icon. Thanks though!

Comment: @オパラ unfortunately we cannot answer that question if we don't know what modifications you did. If you want to share *that* code on a gist/pastebin, I might take a look at it.

Comment: I have shared it though. In the third comment here. https://pastebin.com/eqGQ9WbB

Comment: There seems to be some issue with scope and garbage collection, which is understandable since working with two different toolkit often leads to some issues and unexpected behavior: if you use a function to get the icon instead of having the for loop in the main indentation, the problem doesn't show. The problem seems to be related to the creation of the reference of each `app` of `app_info`. See this: https://gist.github.com/MaurizioB/3ee9a083ffe9d3a9cc817d5154b06e34